# (graphql, prisma) How can i ingnore(pass) check auth when login(signin)?

Tags: authentication, jwt, graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

I have a problem creating graphql server and checking auth. I automatically created schemas with Prisma, and I manually added to the schema by creating a 'signin' mutation. I have also added the jwt checking (auth) middleware, as shown in the following code:

```
server.express.post(
  server.options.endpoint, 
  auth,
  (err, req, res, next) => {
    console.log('bb');
    if (err) return res.status(401).send(err.message)
    next()
  }
)
```

The problem is that the token is checked even when the signin is done.
Is there a way not to confirm tokens when requesting signin interaction, or if so, how do I get over it?
(is it right that there isn't token when client doesn't signed in?)

Answer (score 0):

In your auth middleware, you can access the Request (`req`). You could check to see which operation if called.

- If you are calling the `login` operation, call next()
- Otherwise, check the token